# How to save and retrieve image in SQL Server 2008R2 using Asp.Net via VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have a FileUpload `fileupload2` control and an image box control `image1`. Now I want to save the browsing image and also show it on image box when I browsing the path. I am writing the code like below.

What's the problem in that code and how I show it on image box when I browsing the path?

```
Protected Sub btnsave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsave.Click
    Connection()

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = cn
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Personal_info (image_id,pic)VALUES (@image_id,@pic)"

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@image_id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pic", SqlDbType.Image, 200)

    cmd.Parameters("@image_id").Value = txtid.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@pic").Value = FileUpload2.FileBytes

    Dim i = -1

    i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery

    If i = -1 Then
        lblMessage.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        lblMessage.Text = "Fail to Save"
        'MsgBox("Fail", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
    Else
        lblMessage.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Green
        lblMessage.Text = "Success to Save"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: One issue I see is the `DBType.Image` parameter type. That does not exist according to MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx

You also miss a closing quote in the `MsgBox` line right before the `Else`.

Comment: There is no error msgs. The the image was save as a <byte> in database but problem is that when I retrieve the image into the crystal report or grid-view I saw a blank image.

Answer (score -1):

to show the imange in the image box you need to provide the imange path or url. you cannot read it directly from the database.

one way to do it is to

1. retrieve the imange from the database
2. save the image in the server
3. pass the image box the image server path

   ```
   '1. retrieve the imange from the database
   Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
   cmd.Connection = cn
   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT pic FROM Personal_info  WHERE image_id=@image_id;"

   cmd.Parameters.Add("@image_id", image_id)

   Dim rd As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
   Dim MyData() As Byte
   If rd.Read Then
       If rd("pic").ToString <> Nothing Then
           MyData = rd("pic")
       End If

   End If

   '2. save the image in the server
   Dim oFileStream As New System.IO.FileStream(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "image\image.jpg", System.IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite)
   oFileStream.Write(MyData, 0, MyData.Length)
   oFileStream.Close()

   '3. pass the image box the image server path
   image1.ImageUrl = "~/image/image.jpg"
   ```

Comment: Other way: in a ashx handler under the url retrieve image and put it into output stream. Yes, returning the byte content requries some programming, but it is totally possible for a not total beginner to read the documentation and return the image bytes in a http response. -1.